# What place does post increment and post decrement operators have in the rules of operator precedence in c language

Tags: c, operators, operator-precedence

As per the information in this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators_precedence.htm), post increment and decrement operators have first place. And this [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Operator-Precedence) says " Take this example:

foo = *p++;

Here p is incremented as a side effect of the expression, but foo takes the value of *(p++) rather than (*p)++, since the unary operators bind right to left ".

But after doing it practically nothing happened as information mentioned in those links.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    int *iptr;
    iptr = &i;
    int num = *iptr++;//1) In this expression the value of 'i' is assigned to num. And an attempt of post incrementing the address stored in *iptr is done as side effect.
    printf("Num value: %d\n",num);

    printf("Pointer: %d\n",*iptr);//2) The address of *iptr is not incremented. If it was then the value of 'i' would not be printed instead it would print the incremented address itself.

    printf("Post increment: %d\n",*iptr++);//3) The address of *iptr will be post incremented (which didn't happen in case of num). But for now the value of 'i' will be printed.

    printf("After increment: %d\n",*iptr);//4) Now the incremented address stored in *iptr will be displayed as there is no value assigned to that address.
    return 0;
}
```

In the above experiment the effect of post increment can be seen only after a statement terminator. But no effect can be seen even after a statement terminator if a post increment is done on the right operand of the assignment operator. E.G int num = *iptr++; (as mentioned in the above experiment). So exactly what place does post increment and decrement operators have in the rules of operator precedence.

Comment: How do you know no effect is seen? What does this print for you? What does the effect being seen or not have to do with operator precedence?

Comment: In (1) it is `iptr` that is incremented, not `*iptr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it has undefined behavior: when you point a pointer to a singular local variable, dereferencing incremented pointer yields undefined behavior.

Derefefencing incremented pointers is well-defined for pointers into an array.

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3};
int *iptr = &array[0];
int num = *iptr++;
```

In addition, printing `iptr` using `%d` and dereference operator is incorrect: you need to print it using `%p`, after casting `iptr` to `void*`, without dereferencing:

```
printf("Pointer: %p\n", (void*)iptr);
// No asterisk here -----------^
```

Now everything works as expected ([demo](http://ideone.com/pXLWFG)).

Comment: Disagree with "point a pointer to a singular local variable, incrementing the pointer yields undefined address."  True the incremented pointer should not be de-referenced, but the pointer itself is valid per the "one past" rule and "a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one"  C11 §6.5.6 7-8

Comment: @chux You are right, "one past" rule allows OP to increment pointer once. The second increment should be UB, though. I edited to be more conservative about the UB claim. Thank you!

Comment: BTW Early congrats on 1/2 million.

Comment: @chux Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your efforts.